# Run on a different port than with which buildout was run

Tags: plone, port, buildout

Everywhere I have read, they say the same thing: change port in some kind of config file and run buildout.

That is, a buildout is needed to run plone in a different port.

Why cannot it be like this:

1. `bin/plonectl start`
   starts plone with port numbers mentioned in the config file
2. `bin/plonectl start 8081`
   this port will override the ports mentioned inside the config file

Question: Can I directly edit the port number inside "some file" that
`bin/plonectl start` reads, which file would that be?

You might say, why not run the darn buildout?

My buildout takes at least 15 minutes ... and I *do* intend to run plone on the ports mentioned in that config file, in fact I have a production server that is doing just that.

What I am looking for is:

I want to run buildout with the port number written in a config file (say, 81) but run on a different port (say, 8081) temporarily so that I can do all the edits there (url:8081), while "standard" plone is happily serving its stuff as usual on port 81.

Someone, please give me some direction.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is to edit your buildout to create a *second* instance to run. You'll need to add a ZEO server too, plus the necessary changes to your setup to have the instances connect to that port.

You cannot just change the configuration file to start a second instance on a different port otherwise; to run multiple instances you need, at the very least, a ZEO server or a RelStorage ZODB setup to be able to share access to the object database.

See [the Plone developer manual](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/managing-projects-with-buildout/a-deployment-configuration) on how to set up multiple instances and a ZEO server for your setup.

And if your buildout takes 15 minutes to run, then it sounds like your buildout is perhaps doing too much network connection checking. Try running it with the `-N` switch to switch off the default 'newer package' checks.

As for the configuration file used by `bin/plonectl`, that would be `parts/plonectl/etc/zope.conf`. Generally speaking, a `bin/partname` instance script is paired with a `parts/partname` directory, and Zope instances look for a `etc/zope.conf` file there for configuration. Altering files by hand in `parts/partname` directories will be lost when re-running buildout, as it'll generate new copies.

Comment: Even better, use the "-o" flag to run offline. ("-N" is default behavior unless you've specified differently in your buildout.) Skip the "-o" flag when you need to add or update a package.